# How to count the number of plural words given a list of words in order to find the fraction

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, input, fractions

I'm trying to complete this homework problem:

**Problem #1:** "Write a program that asks the user for a list of nouns (separated by spaces) and approximates the fraction that are plural by counting the fraction that end in "s". Your program should output the total number of words and the fraction that end in "s". You should assume that words are separated by spaces (and ignore the possibility of tabs and punctuation between words).

1. First, count the number of words in the string the user entered (**Hint**: count the number of spaces). Print out the number of words. Make sure this works before going onto the next part.
2. Next, ignoring the last word (which is a special case and can be dealt with separately), count the number of words ending in 's' (**Hint**: count the number of "s "). Test that this part works before going on to the next step.
3. Last, check the last word to see if it ends in "s"-- since it's the last word, the "s" will always occur at the same index in the string.*

**Problem #2:** If we count the number of S's, that'll count all S's in the word, not just the last one. How can I go about figuring out if the last letter in each given word ends with an S. I have this so far:

```
noun = input("Enter nouns: ")
print("You entered: ", noun)
words = noun.split()
print(words)
amount = len(words)
print(amount)
```

I don't think I could simply do a `words.count('s')`. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Would `str.endswith()` be a good place to start?

Comment: (hint: count the number of `"s "`) There's a space inside those quotes.

Comment: Or index into the word with `[-1]` and check what character it is

Comment: @G.Anderson We haven't learned endswith() yet so we're, unfortunately, not able to use it. Though I was tempted.

Comment: OMG, @BilltheLizard I didn't even notice that! This is so much more sense now. To think I spent hours racking my brain on this last night *face palm*. Also explains saving the last word for later and doing something a bit different.

Comment: It's easy to miss if you're reading that text in a variable-width font (as you most likely would be if your assignment is in a Word document).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Billthelizard hint it looks like the easiest solution is this case is:

```
plurals = noun.count('s ')
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Will work same with user input, use `.split()` and `str.endswith()`

```
data = 'cat dogs people lovers'
y = data.split()
print(len(y))
x = [i for i in y[:-1] if i.endswith('s')]
print(len(x))
if y[-1].endswith('s'):
    print(y[-1])
```

Without using `.endswith()`

```
y = data.split()
print(len(y))
x = [i for i in y[:-1] if i[-1] == 's']
print(len(x))
if y[-1][-1] == 's':
    print(y[-1])
```

Comment: Thank you, the third line of your suggestion really helped!

Comment: @Mcunning No prob glad it worked out ! If this solved your problem appreciate if you accepted answer, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a simple list comprehension:

```
test_input = 'apples carrots pickles tractor tree goat friends people'

plurals = [i for i in test_input.split() if i.endswith('s')]

total = len(plurals)
fraction = total/len(test_input.split())
```

If you are not able to use `endswith()`, then you can use indexing:

```
plurals = [i for i in test_input.split() if i[-1]=='s']
```

Note that `split()` will split the input string on spaces (`' '`) by default.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone! @billthelizard @toti08 @vash_the_stampede and @rahlf23 your responses really really helped. Using your suggestions I finally got to the correct code. I'll list it below for anyone else that may happen upon this question. Thanks again!

```
noun = input("Enter nouns: ")
print("You entered: ", noun)
words = noun.split()
print(words)
amount = len(words)
print(amount)
plural = noun.count('s ')

for i in noun:
    if i[-1] == "s":
        last = 1
    else:
        last = 0

plurals = plural + last
print(plurals)

fraction = plurals / amount
print(fraction)
```